# Swift control flow counting with multiples

Tags: swift

Write a function that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print “x” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “y”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “z”.

I have been presented this question as a student and am having trouble trying to figure out how to switch the multiples from numbers to the respective words. in this sense I placed as "x, y, and z".

I can make the function count to 100, just not sure how to, first of all, target the multiples. After that, convert them to words instead of numbers. This is what I have so far.

func count(from:Int, to:Int = 100){for i in from...to{print(i)}}

Thank you for any help in advance! If you may also explain why it works the way it does it would be greatly appreciated! learning still!

Comment: Try to explain your problem more. I can't Understand what are you looking for

Comment: I need to write a function that counts from 1 to 100. Then for the multiples of 3, i need to replace the number with a word. Then with the multiples of 5. Finally with the multiples of both 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on "fizz buzz".

You could use a `map()` function for this. You'd map each number to a string: Numbers that were not "special" would be mapped to their string equivalent, and numbers that were "special" would be mapped to their replacements. A switch statement would be a good way to select the "special" numbers.

Alternately you could use a for loop and a multi-part if statement:

```
for number in 1...100 {
   //if statements
}
```

You can tell if a number is divisible by another number using the modulo (`%`) operator: ( `number % 3 ==`  is true if a number is divisible by 3.)

Comment: Note that using `map` would convert an array of Ints to an array of strings. Alternately you could use a `forEach` statement where you'd loop through the numbers and again use a `switch` statement to decide what to print for each one. The `map()` function maps an array of something to an array of changed values. The `forEach` statement, on the other hand, simply iterates through the values in the array.

Comment: `map` seems pretty advanced for someone who hasn't yet mastered conditionals. (Not that there's anything wrong with that -- we all start somewhere.)

Comment: Good point Caleb. I forget how odd `map` would seem to a beginner. I augmented my answer with other options.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to read this first:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

If you just need to print the results:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 {
        print("z")
    } else if i % 3 == 0 {
        print("x")
    } else if i % 5 == 0 {
        print("y")
    } else {
        print("\(i)")
    }
}
```

or the same solution, but with switch:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    switch (i % 3 == 0, i % 5 == 0) {
    case (true, true): print("z")
    case (true, _): print("x")
    case (_, true):  print("y")
    default: print("\(i)")
    }
}
```